# Frontend Invoice Print

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend, invoice, print

Just a question. My frontend button on the customer dashboard to print an invoice prints the page itself and not the PDF of the invoice.

Does anyone have any idea if there is a quick fix or a setting for this?

How it looks now :

[image: How it not should be]

How the pdf looks when printed from admin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento, the Front page doesn’t generate PDF for order. So, there is no a quick fix or setting. We need to build a custom one (can try with domPdf library). When allowing customer generating PDF, we should create a cron job to clear the generated files.

Comment: good point about the 'clear' part but shouldn't magento need to save the invoice fille location and only create a new one if that one does not exist instead of creating new ones?

Comment: Also i don't get why i need to build a new PDF just for the frontend. I made a custom PDF for the backend so shouldn't i just need to enable that on the frontend then?

Comment: Not test yet. But seem that Magento always create a new PDF file.

Comment: Hmmn i think it would be for the benefit for the community if we maybe could come up with an opensource module that not only doesn't create duplicate PDF's  (unless updated) but also prints it on the frontend. Its just such a standard feature..